# What methods are there to connect arduino to a raspberry pi

Tags: wifi, connection

I would like to do this in order to use the wifi dongle on my pi

Comment: Isn't it easier to connect you wifi dongle to the pi _without_ an arduino in the middle? Or did I misunderstand the question?

Comment: The question is poorly written, and it's already a topic that is very well discussed.

Comment: Welcome to Raspberry Pi SE.  Please take a few moments and take the tour (and earn a badge) by going here:  https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/Tour - it really helps to explain how this one works.

Answer (score 3):

There are several methods to do so:

1. Connecting the arduino via the USB connector on the RaspberryPi and controlling it as you would do from a PC.
2. Using a specially designed shield (for RaspberryPi), as Alamode ([Alamode web site](http://wyolum.com/projects/alamode/)).
3. Build yourself that shield, as in: http://www.instructables.com/id/The-Raspberry-Pi-Arduino-Connection/

But if what you are looking for is to give Arduino wifi connectivity using the RaspberryPi as a "wifi shield" for the arduino, I think that maybe you are being a bit overengineering it.

Comment: By far #1 is the simplest and most functional.  Install the Arduino IDE on the Rpi and use the regular serial cable to program it.  Then use that cable (on /dev/ttyUSB0) so your Python programs can interact with the Arduino.  In most cases you can have the USB provide all the power the Arduino needs, especially if it is a Nano.  On mine, I can RDP into the Rpi and see how it is working and change the programs on either end very quickly.  Upvote, @carlesm.

Answer (score 2):

You could also use a device like this:
http://www.instructables.com/id/How-to-use-and-Arduino-shield-with-the-Raspberry-P/

Which is designed by Dexter Industries here:  http://www.dexterindustries.com/Arduberry
"The Arduberry marries the Raspberry Pi and the Arduino."  It's entirely open source.

Basically, this is an Arduino that connects to the Pi, and allows you to either stack Arduino shields on top, or to access the GPIOs.  You can program the Arduino directly from the Raspberry Pi over the GPIOs.

[image: Raspberry Pi and Arduino Shield Connector Arduberry With a Shield,]

[image: Raspberry Pi and Arduino Shield Connector Arduberry Using GPIOs to control an LED.]